# Read json file using django python

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I have a json file.I want to read json file in django python.

Json file contains

```
{
    "ATM Cash" : ["withdrawal"],
    "Expense" :["fees","goods","stationery","purchase","material","telephone"],
    "Income" : ["salary","deposit","rewards"],
    "Payment" : ["tranfer","payment"],
    "Medical" : ["dr ", 
       "doctor","dr.","nursing","pharmacist","physician","hospital","medicine"],
    "Food/Restaurent" :["food","catering"],
    "Groceries" : ["big bazar"],
    "Shopping" : ["cloths"],
    "Mobile recharge" : ["airtel"],
    "Auto & Fuel" : ["fuel"],
    "Travel" : ["travel"],
    "General" : ["others"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json 

    json_data = '{
        "ATM Cash" : ["withdrawal"],
        "Expense" :["fees","goods","stationery","purchase","material","telephone"],
        "Income" : ["salary","deposit","rewards"],
        "Payment" : ["tranfer","payment"],
        "Medical" : ["dr ", 
           "doctor","dr.","nursing","pharmacist","physician","hospital","medicine"],
        "Food/Restaurent" :["food","catering"],
        "Groceries" : ["big bazar"],
        "Shopping" : ["cloths"],
        "Mobile recharge" : ["airtel"],
        "Auto & Fuel" : ["fuel"],
        "Travel" : ["travel"],
        "General" : ["others"]
    }'


    data = json.loads(json_data)
```

just do this but please follow the basic tutorial first.

Comment: Your answer is right since json_data is a string in your case. He wants to read it from a file. So he should use json.load() instead of json.loads(). BTW if you do not like to answer the questions posted by newbies then you can just skip it instead of discouraging.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a file then use `json.load()` like

```
import json
with open('path/to/file/file_name.json', 'r') as f:
    my_json_obj = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import json
def read_file(path):
    file = open(path, "r")
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data

def read_json(path):
    return json.loads(read_file(path))

def write_json(path, data):
     return write_file(path, json.dumps(data))

def write_file(path, data):
   file = open(path, "w")
   file.write(str(data))
   file.close()
   return data
```

I find these functions, created by MkNxGn, Are very useful for writing and reading files, including those in json.